# Nested grep option in Mocha (or another way of selecting exacly one test)

Tags: grep, mocha.js

In Mocha we can use `--grep` flag for selecting specific test for running:

```
mocha --grep 'my test'
```

But when numbers of tests raises, come specific test cases can share the same name, what makes single grep insufficient. I'd love to have something like "nested grep" to be able to select tests more specifically, regarding its parents. Can it be possible? Or maybe there are some other options to select a test for running more specific way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fortunately I discovered that we can do something like this:

```
mocha /path/to/specific/file -g 'pattern for specific test case'
```

It solves my problem as long as case names don't repeat in the scope of one file (but they generally shouldn't).